# same pointer showing different sizes in different compilers

Tags: c, pointers, sizeof

I have run the following code on Turbo C compiler and 
GNU compiler:

```
int main()
{
   char *cptr;
   printf("%d\n",sizeof(cptr));
   return 0;
}
```

and I had output '**2**' on the Turbo C run and output '**4**' on GNU compiler run.
I am on a 64 bit machine.
Can anyone explain the fact behind such differences to me?

Answer (score 3):

Turbo C, which is vintage, is probably building for a 16-bit DOS machine, which has small pointers by default.

Answer (score 2):

If we consider the DOS-based Turbo-C compiler, the addresses are limited to the range 0x0000 to 0xFFFF (0-65535), so the size of the pointer is 2 bytes. On the other hand, if we consider the 32-bit GNU compiler, millions of addresses are created there, so the size is 4 bytes.

The size of the pointer depends only the C compiler you are using, but not on the OS.

Answer (score 1):

Turbo C is a 16 bit, so you get 2 for `sizeof(cptr)`.

Answer (score 1):

Just because your machine is natively 64-bits does not mean every bit of software you may run on it will take advantage of it. The 64-bit machines (and supporting software) are designed to be upward compatible with 32-bit. Software written for 32-bit machines is able to run as a result.

Comment: Basically what you want to say is my Turbo C compiler is 16 bit and GNU compiler is 32 bit???

Answer (score 0):

Basically, the sizeof pointer is the sizeof the integer type used by pointer. Precisely speaking, 32 bit int on 32 bit platform, 64 bit int (long long) on 64 bit platform. 
But be careful, it also depends on the compiler you are using. Which means, even on 64 bit platform, if you are using a 32 bit compiler (or even 16 bit), still 32 bit int will be used for the type of pointer.
From your result, it looks that you turbo C compiler is definitely not 64 bit (should be 16 bit, if I did not remember it wrong). While your gcc compiler is real 64 bit.

Comment: it looks my Turbo C is 16 bit and GNU is 32 bit. Do you have any way to find out the compiler architecture that is, whether it 16 or 32 or 64 bit??

Comment: I think an easy way to find out is, just print out the value of sizeof(int) and sizeof(long). Because both int and long are platform (compiler dependend), which means on 16 bit platform (compiler), int is 16 bit, otherwise 32. on 64 bit platform and compiler, long is 64 bit, otherwise 32. So: 1. if the sizeof(int) is 2 byte (16 bit), then you have a definitely 16 bit compiler. 2 if the sizeof(long) is 4 byte (64 bit), then you have 64 bit compiler. 3. Other cases 32 bit compiler. Hope it helps

Comment: at your second decision 4 byte(64 bit) how??

Comment: @who9137: 4 bytes is 32 bits, not 64 bits.  And pointer type sizes are *not* necessarily dependent on integer type sizes; they're determined by the available address range for a process.  Also, there have been word-addressed architectures where `char *` was *wider* than `int *` to account for the offset into the word.

Comment: @JohnBode, Sorry for confusing, dont know what i was thinking, what a shame. Of course, 4 bytes is 32bits. So correct comment is when sizeof(long) is 8 bytes (64bits).

Answer (score 0):

Different platforms may have different sizes for any given pointer type.  It all depends on the underlying memory architecture and the address space available to any given process.  Never assume pointer types will always have a specific size.